# How to build a Signed APK? How to figure out if an APK is already signed or not?

Tags: android-studio

My dev insisted to build a signed APK on his end. What I wanted from him was help in building the signed APK on my end. I shared my screen with him and gave him the control of my desktop. He even gave me a .jks file.

As far as I know that a signed apk must be built by the app owner as .jks file is generated using some personal details.

How can I check whether the apk I have is not signed already. Should I go do the Play Store App Signing up instead of using a keysotre file?

I didn't try anything yet. I am just trying to solve this issue. If there is any detailed video tutorial is available, please share. Thank you.

Comment: Jks file has password, alias and alias password. Use these three to sing your apk.

Comment: Unsigned apk usually has unsigned written in file name if build through gradle.